# How to specify the JDK version in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, gradle, directory-structure

Android Studio is giving me a Gradle build error that looks like this:

```
Error:(3, 22) compileSdkVersion android-22 requires compiling with JDK 7
```

Now it gives me these clickable prompts:

```
Download JDK 7
Select a JDK from the File System
Open build.gradle File
```

And I have already downloaded and installed JDK 7. The problem is when I go to select it in the "File System" i can only find a directory named 1.6.0 JDK. Furthermore, the installation of JDK 7 skipped the bullet point where I would've selected the install directory, so I'm really not sure where it is. My java control panel says I have "Java 7 Update 79" so I'm pretty sure I'm close, I just need to tell android studio where it is. I also ran the `java -version` command in the terminal and it says my version is "1.7.0_79".

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: In my case, using Win 7, the default installation path is `C:\Program files\Java\", see if it was installed in there.

Answer (score 254, accepted):

You can use <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> for Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> for Windows/Linux to pull up the Settings dialog. Then, go to "Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle". In there, you can set the JDK location.

[image: Gradle Settings]

To get your JDK location, run `/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11` in terminal. Send 1.7 for Java 7, 1.8 for Java 8, or 11 for Java 11.

Comment: Right but I don't know where the JDK is installed. JDK seven did not install in the same directory as JDK 6. Is there a way to find where JDK 7 installed? Because according to terminal and the java control panel, I have Java version 1.7.0_79, I just don't know where it is, because it isn't next to JDK 6.

Comment: Ah. Sorry about that. That's not what you asked :) I'll see if I can find info on the install location. I don't remember offhand where 7 gets installed on Windows

Comment: @ThePartyTurtle Are you on Windows, Mac, or Linux. Well, either way, [use this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4681109/2448305) to get the location.

Comment: Should've specified! I'm on a Mac. And yea it's interesting it didn't install it into the same directory. Also if my terminal and Java control panel are telling me I have 1.7.0_79, does that necessarily mean I have JDK 7?

Comment: I would say yea that means you have it. What do you get when you run which java in terminal?

Comment: When I run java -version, I get this:                                                            java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: I've added the command to the bottom of my answer that will get you your JDK location.

Answer (score 74):

### Android Studio Arctic Fox (2020.3.1)

In Android Studio Arctic Fox (2020.3.1 Patch 4), the JDK Location setting is moved to:

```
File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle > Gradle JDK
```

### Up to Android Studio 4.2

You can follow the answer from Ben Kane, the JDK Location setting is located in:

```
File > Project Structure > SDK Location
```

Comment: How do I change this globally for **all** projects created now and in the future in Arctic Fox?

Comment: I'm not seeing Gradle JDK in Arctic Fox.

Comment: The top example is only the JDK for gradle, what about the JDK for the rest of the system used for building and compiling code?

Comment: @AndrewS It seems like that this jdk version is used for everything in the progect

Comment: @userVadim, From my experience following this question, I am sure you are correct. I really with it was labeled and located as so. It causes unnecessary confusion.

Comment: I can confirm `File > Project Structure > SDK Location` is useless. I had to change my `JAVA_PATH` and add the java version to use in the `PATH` on Windows.

Answer (score 30):

For new Android Studio versions, go to C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin(or to location of Android Studio installed files) and open command window at this location and type in following command in command prompt:-

```
java -version
```

Comment: the best answer!

Comment: Why is this upvoted? This doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: This is wrong.  Android Studio has a setting for which JDK to use, and this is just one of the options, so this just tells you which version that copy is, not which version you're using.

Comment: I saw that there was a jre folder in programfiles\java folder, so I deleted the jar folder in AndroidStudio folder :)) and your answer led me to the solution

Answer (score 8):

[image: Check the JDK you use in Android Studio]

The `gradle sync` uses the following JDK location:

In Android Studio, `File` -> `Project Structure`

Navigate to the `SDK Location`.

[image: Android Studio 4.1.0 JDK Location]

```
cd /Applications/Android\ Studio\ 4.1.0.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home

➜  Home ./bin/java --version
openjdk 11.0.8 2020-07-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6916264)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6916264, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 6):

On a Mac, you can use terminal to go to `/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home` (or wherever your Android SDK is installed) and enter the following in the command prompt:

```
./java -version
```

Comment: Also using a Mac but I always get "No Java runtime present, requesting install.", even if I go the the specified folder.
What worked is `export JAVA_HOME=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home ` and then `java -version`

Answer (score 3):

In Android Studio 4.0.1, Help -> About shows the details of the Java version used by the studio, in my case:

```
Android Studio 4.0.1
Build #AI-193.6911.18.40.6626763, built on June 25, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1237M
Cores: 8
Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: com.google.services.firebase
```

Comment: The version of Java running Android Studio isn't necessarily the same as the version being used by Gradle.

Answer (score 3):

1. gradle.properties:org.gradle.java.home=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home
2. ./gradlew assembleDebug -Dorg.gradle.java.home=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home

Comment: I tried EVERYTHING. Only This Worked! I am using studio version 4.1.2. Would see if upgrading Android Studio works.

Comment: for ubunut 20.x, in you gradle.properties file 
`org.gradle.java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java` or whereever you install jdk 11. (in ubuntu it defaults to above path.)

Answer (score 2):

This is old question but still my answer may help someone

For checking Java version in android studio version , 
simply open Terminal of Android Studio and type

```
java -version
```

This will display java version installed in android studio

Comment: There are already two answers that suggest this exact solution. Please be sure to review existing answers before contributing your own. If they’re correct, upvote them. Of your answer is meaningfully different, it may be worth editing it to explain why.

Comment: This doesn't work. It gives you the version of java used by the system, not the one used by Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

For the latest version (**2022.2.1 Patch 2**) at this time, The setting has been moved to gradle setting.

So just open the project structure through **File** > **Project Structure**, Select **SDK Location** from left menu, click on **Gradle Settings**.

Here select the Gradle JDK you want. I would suggest to select the **Android Studio Java Home** option.

[image: Android Studio Gradle Setting]

Answer (score 1):

to set the Java version from the android studio terminal write this command on the terminal (MAC)

cammand ->
export JAVA_HOME='-- java home path (can get from Preferences-> Build,Execution,Deployement -> Gradle'

example (set java 11)->

```
export JAVA_HOME='/Applications/jdk-11.0.16.1.jdk/Contents/Home'
```

then you can check whether is it changed or not using `java -version` command