# Android peer not authenticated

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Everything has been working, only today i started to get an error message, and i can't even "Sync Project with Gradle files" from Android Studio. The only thing i have changed was ... the office :D

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   Could not download library.jar (com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.16)
>   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/mcxiaoke/volley/library/1.0.16/library-1.0.16.jar'.
>   peer not authenticated

And my build.grade

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven'}
        maven { url 'http://dl.bintray.com/amulyakhare/maven'}
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
    }
}
....
```

gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.3-all.zip
```

I also tried with **http** instead of **https**, but still the same problem.

Does anyone have similar problem?

Comment: jcenter has invalid SSL and brokes all gradle build. Maven works :)

Comment: Thanks for the update @MariuszS. What do you mean by: Maven works? What do you suggest to fix this error?

Comment: maven is using m2 repository, solution belowa

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Temporary solution**

Add this to build.gradle

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        name "jcenter"
        url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
    }
}
```

Comment: Disabling https should only be used as a temporary workaround!

Comment: Yes! This is temporary solution

Answer (score 7):

It seems a temporary issue with `jcenter` with an invalid SSL.

You can switch to `mavenCentral` repo in your `build.gradle` file.

```
repositories {
     mavenLocal()
     mavenCentral()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurs when cacerts file gets messed up. After attempting all solutions that I found on the Internet, I could finally resolve this by reinstalling java.

Answer (score 0):

Add these properties to your gradle home directory in a new **gradle.properties** file

```
systemProp.https.proxyHost=[your proxy https host IP or DNS name]
systemProp.https.proxyPort=[your proxy https port, usually 8080]
systemProp.http.proxyHost=[your proxy http host IP or DNS name]
systemProp.http.proxyPort=[your proxy http port, usually 8080]
```

> OSX: /users/yourusername/.gradle/gradle.properties
>
> Windows: C:\Users\yourusername.gradle\gradle.properties

Then, restart Android Studio and open your project.

Note: I used the same values for HTTP and HTTPS, they could be different from yours.

Answer (score 0):

changing the version of the jdk to the latest version worked for me (Oracle Java 8). This question shows you how to do this on android studio: [How to specify the JDK version in android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30631286/how-to-specify-the-jdk-version-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

I tried with all the above solutions didn't work, this once helped me lot with latest studio 2.2 preview 7. Make the changes in build.gradle of root project:

```
    allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter {
            url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"    
                }

       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and it was happening because of a VPN proxy issue. I disabled my VPN and everything worked fine after. I used this command (on a Mac):

```
sudo /opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/acwebsecagent -disablesvc -websecurity
```