# Peer not authenticated Android Studio

Tags: android, maven, intellij-idea, build

I am working on a project. after integrating `crashlytics` bug reporting tool android studio does not sync project completely and it give error. Error i am facing is

> Error:Cause: peer not authenticated

from two days i am working on this. but i am not unable to sort out the actual reason behind this. i have read almost every thread regarding this problem but not succeed.

The following solution which i have tried are as follow.

> [Android Studio Gradle build failed. Error:Cause: peer not authenticated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26734738/android-studio-gradle-build-failed-errorcause-peer-not-authenticated#)
>
> [Android Studio / Intellij, Gradle Error:Cause: peer not authenticated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27206040/android-studio-intellij-gradle-errorcause-peer-not-authenticated)
>
> [Gradle Could not HEAD https://..pom > peer not authenticated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26675814/gradle-could-not-head-https-pom-peer-not-authenticated)
>
> [Android peer not authenticated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30799261/android-peer-not-authenticated)

Comment: Whats the maven link you have for fabric, use http:// in it ..

Comment: @rizwan, did you found any solution for this. I am facing same issue from few days.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking versions of all the tools that you are using in your project. Make sure that all belongs to same version that is available with your tool.