# Run Android Studio with JRE 1.8 or later version

Tags: java, android

I am facing issue for Android N layout XML preview. it is showing following message :

"Android N requires the IDE to be running with Java 1.8 or later"

also i install JAVA 1.8 in my OS.

also change the project JDK location with Java 1.8.

but when i see help->about of android studio it is show always 1.7.

how can i change it.?

[image: here is the image when help->about JRE:1.7]

Comment: Did you set JAVA_HOME variable in environment variables?

Comment: @imesha yes i tried that but it is not working. :(

Comment: i have install 1.7,1.8 in my OS.. is it effect that.?

Comment: Android studio take the JDK at JAVA_HOME as the java version in it. Please double check whether you have set the 1.8 directory as JAVA_HOME

Comment: yes @ImeshaSudasingha i tried both. still facing issue. let me check again

Comment: Related post - [How to specify the JDK version in android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30631286/465053)

Answer (score 23):

Go to File -> Project Structure --> SDK Location and check JDK location to set jdk 1.8 or not

See the attached screenshot for more

[image]

Comment: This solution was the only working one for me. Thank you ! :-)

Comment: Great solution, I was battling different system Java versions, and it is quite an elegant solution to point to the JDK that ships with Android Studio.

Answer (score 11):

Android Studio might show the Java Version that it is set to use as 1.7, but your project can still be set to use 1.8.

Firstly add the following to your gradle file (Refer to: [Official Android Dev - Java 8 in Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/preview/j8-jack.html))

```
defaultConfig {
...
    jackOptions {
      enabled true
    }
  }
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
```

Secondly go to "File" -> "Project" -> "SDK Location"

Check that the JDK Location is pointing to 1.8 and not 1.7

Running your Android N emulator should now work. Regardless of whether Android Studio itself states it's using 1.7 or 1.8.

---

Follow the guidelines that are provided on the Android site:

[Set up for Android N](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/preview/setup-sdk.html)

Comment: android N emulator i can run. but the problem is that, when i see the layout xml file preview then it show "Android N requires the IDE to be running with Java 1.8 or later" so i want to run android studio with jre 1.8

Comment: Follow the guidelines I provided. Ensure you have set your JDK location correctly

Comment: Check that your default JDK is the Oracle JDK and not OpenJDK. Many distributions ship with OpenJDK by default due to licensing issues and even if you install the Oracle JDK it might not then be the default. Running java -version from a terminal should tell you which is the default.

Comment: Remove all versions of Java that you have installed, and only install Java 8 - http://www.linuxdeveloper.space/install-android-studio-oracle-jdk/

Answer (score 9):

You have to set JAVA_HOME in your operating system.

Windows

1. Install the JDK 1.8 and note the destination path, usually  **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_xx**
2. Right-click  **My Computer** and select **Properties.**
3. Click the **Advanced System Settings** link in the left column.
4. In the tab **Advanced** click **Environment Variables**
5. Create or modify the variable **JAVA_HOME**.
6. Enter the variable value as the installation path for the Java Development Kit.

[image]

Linux

[How to set JAVA_HOME in Linux for all users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641536/how-to-set-java-home-in-linux-for-all-users)

OSX

[What should I set JAVA_HOME to on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348842/what-should-i-set-java-home-to-on-osx)

Comment: Thank you, it worked, but user must restart Android Studio to fetch the new environment variable we created.

Comment: Great, thank you! I'm a Windows user, and this solved my issue.

Comment: So, i did, it always saying the current JDK is 1.7... Solution of Khalid worked

Answer (score 2):

As Krishna Meena is mentioning you should change the SDK/JDK Location settings found from within:
File -> Project Structure... then SDK Location and now press on the link Gradle Settings...

[image]

Then choose your Gradle JDK to use...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As it is mentioned in the [documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration/osx-jdk) you can add the STUDIO_JDK env var to configure the IDE JDK. In order to access it from your GUI, you can add this line to your ~/.profile file :

```
launchctl setenv STUDIO_JDK /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk<version>.jdk
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. I posted a follow-up question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/58677216/9636

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using windows 7/8/10 with 64bits

**just install jdk with x86 version** 
No need to reset your environment variable. that will remain same as you have declared.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Choose the API 23 from the list as picture]

Choose the API 23 from the list as picture

Answer (score 0):

just add the tag below, in your build.gradel ( app level file), under android{ } tag,

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

like this,

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.code"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

}

And now you are good to go.