# Error while running app in debug mode and while building release apk in flutter

Tags: flutter

My flutter sdk version is 2.2.1 and dart sdk version is 2.13 . Flutter doctor shows everything is fine. Problem occurred while building release apk for the first time. After that running in debug mode shows error also! here is the pic[image: error]

Comment: try replacing -> with => in you FlutterLocation file. Also remove '{' after lamda expression

Answer (score 0):

please change your java SDK 7 to Java 8 to support lambda expressions.

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36638657/run-android-studio-with-jre-1-8-or-later-version