# IntelliJ IDEA Buildtools 24.0.2 requires Java 1.8 or above. Current JDK version is 1.7

Tags: java, android, macos, intellij-idea, android-sdk-tools

After trying to build my project in Mac OS X El Capitan I've got this error:

> Error:Gradle: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Buildtools 24.0.2 requires Java 1.8 or above.  Current JDK version is 1.7.

I have project with `build.gradle` section like this:

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Also:

> Project SDK 1.8.0_101
>
> App Module: android sdk 24, jdk 1.8,
>
> Root Module: android sdk 24, jdk 1.8
>
> compileSdkVersion 24
>
> buildToolsVersion '24.0.2'
>
> minSdkVersion 16
>
> targetSdkVersion 24
>
> retrolambda

P.S.: I successfully built this project from command line.

Comment: run this project in Android Studio. It may be issue with your IDEA version comapbility

Comment: @piotrek1543 thanks but I want to use IDEA instead Android Studio. But now yes, I use damn Android Studio for working with my project.

Comment: so it works in AS, but not in IntelliJ?

Comment: @piotrek1543 exactly. Before I've used Ubuntu which have solution but not for Mac OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After checking IDEA global settings I've found solution:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/26mz2d2mbir1r2j/Screen%20Shot%202016-09-01%20at%209.56.37%20PM.png?dl=0

Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle -> Gradle JVM -> Set to 1.8 and this works!

Answer (score 6):

Since you successfully built it in the command line, it seems like it's a problem with your project JDK. The JDK location setting is located in `File>Project Structure>SDK Location --> JDK Location`. If it says anything about `jdk1.7.0`, then switch the jdk to 1.8 by clicking the `...` button to the right of the prompt and give it the file path of jdk1.8.

**EDIT:** If you don't know the path of the jdk, run `ls -l 'which java'` in the terminal.

Comment: IDEA doesn't contains `SDK Location` menu. IDEA only have `Project` menu which have 1.8 with `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home` path . Your advice actual only for Android Studio.

Comment: `which java` says:

`/usr/bin/java`

Comment: if you type `ls -l 'which java'` it outputs --> `/usr/bin/java -> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/JDKNUMBERjdk/Contents/Home/bin/java` @AlexanderEfremenkov

Comment: Do you really about Mac OS? Because I've this:

`ls: which java: No such file or directory`

Comment: try `ls -l `\`which java\` (tics instead of single quotes)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have correct versions defined under:
File -> Project Structure -> Project -> Project SDK -> Project Language Level (this is for mac, but I think you can find it for windows using the same logic).

Comment: Did you check the solutions in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30631286/how-to-specify-the-jdk-version-in-android-studio

Comment: This solution for android studio, please check links before answering

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your project structure tab? The solutions in that thread could also work if you are not using android studio.

Comment: of course: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/as6fpxr0l8t8j83/AABHE_K0X697dKlhky1rs_MPa?dl=0

Comment: was this project initially created in android studio? or intellij idea?

Comment: It's doesn't matter because project successfully builds from command line.

Comment: it does matter for your IDE, because it doesn't build your project. If you had it in Android Studio initially and want to move it / moved it to IntelliJ Idea maybe this can help you: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/importing-an-existing-android-project.html

Comment: This advice not help dude