# Is it possible to force Android Studio to compile using a previous jdk?

Tags: android, android-studio, xamarin-studio, jdk1.7, java-8

I am using Android Studio to compile an aar file to use on Xamarin Studio on a project that is currently using other jars compiled on jdk 1.7.0-79, but Android Studio forces me to compile using jdk 1.8.

When I try to use the library on Xamarin if a don't change the JDK version used I can't see the main class and it tells me this warning:
missing class error was raised while reflecting myClass : android/content/Context : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (J2XA006)

If I change the JDK to version 1.8 it gives me this error:
Couldn't load class com/datecs/audioreader/AudioReaderHelper$1 : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/datecs/audioreader/AudioReader$OnUpdateFirmwareListener (J2X9001)

I can't recompile the second library using the latest JDK because I don't have the code and it is too risky to ask for a new version.

Is there a way to compile my library using a previous JDK? Can it be done in Android Studio?

Edit:
[image: I already tried to downgrade the jdk but it won't allow me]

Comment: downgrade the JDK and then recompile. What's the problem in that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to specify the JDK version in android studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30631286/how-to-specify-the-jdk-version-in-android-studio)

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal it won't allow me, do you know how to do it?