# How to fix android error major version 53 is newer than 52 on MacBook

Tags: java, android, macos, android-studio, gradle

Am getting error during build, if am using `compileSdkVersion 30`, `targetSdkVersion 30` and `buildToolsVersion = '30.0.0'`. The error doesn't stop my app from running but I think it might crash on production. Please anyone have an idea how to can fix this instead of using `compileSdkVersion 29`?

I checked online but from other question I see, I couldn't see the steps in my Android Studio 4.0 on Macbook. I also tried changing to `sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_9 targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_9`, but I got so many error.

> warning:
> /Users/pc/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-30/optional/org.apache.http.legacy.jar(org/apache/http/impl/client/BasicCookieStore.class):
> major version 53 is newer than 52, the highest major version supported
> by this compiler.   It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
>
> warning:
> /Users/pc/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-30/optional/org.apache.http.legacy.jar(org/apache/http/impl/cookie/BasicClientCookie.class):
> major version 53 is newer than 52, the highest major version supported
> by this compiler.   It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
>
> warning:
> /Users/pc/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-30/optional/org.apache.http.legacy.jar(org/apache/http/impl/client/BasicCookieStore.class):
> major version 53 is newer than 52, the highest major version supported
> by this compiler.   It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
>
> warning:
> /Users/pc/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-30/optional/org.apache.http.legacy.jar(org/apache/http/impl/cookie/BasicClientCookie.class):
> major version 53 is newer than 52, the highest major version supported
> by this compiler.   It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
>
> warning:
> /Users/pc/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-30/optional/org.apache.http.legacy.jar(org/apache/http/impl/client/BasicCookieStore.class):
> major version 53 is newer than 52, the highest major version supported
> by this compiler.   It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
>
> warning:
> /Users/pc/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-30/optional/org.apache.http.legacy.jar(org/apache/http/impl/cookie/BasicClientCookie.class):
> major version 53 is newer than 52, the highest major version supported
> by this compiler.   It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
>
> warning:
> /Users/pc/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/30.0.0/core-lambda-stubs.jar(java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.class): major version 53 is newer than 52, the highest major version supported
> by this compiler.   It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
>
> warning:
> /Users/pc/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-30/optional/org.apache.http.legacy.jar(org/apache/http/cookie/SetCookie.class):
> major version 53 is newer than 52, the highest major version supported
> by this compiler.   It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
>
> warning:
> /Users/pc/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-30/optional/org.apache.http.legacy.jar(org/apache/http/cookie/Cookie.class):
> major version 53 is newer than 52, the highest major version supported
> by this compiler.   It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
>
> warning:
> /Users/pc/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-30/optional/org.apache.http.legacy.jar(org/apache/http/cookie/ClientCookie.class):
> major version 53 is newer than 52, the highest major version supported
> by this compiler.   It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
>
> warning:
> /Users/pc/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-30/optional/org.apache.http.legacy.jar(org/apache/http/client/CookieStore.class):
> major version 53 is newer than 52, the highest major version supported
> by this compiler.   It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
>
> Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API. Note:
> Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. 11 warnings

My Gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    //compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"
    //buildToolsVersion = '29.0.3'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.android"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        //targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 12
        versionName "2.0.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            debuggable false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('/Users/key.keystore')
            storePassword 'HJJ'
            keyPassword 'KK'
            keyAlias = 'V'
        }
        release {
            storeFile file('/Users/key.keystore')
            storePassword 'HJJ'
            keyPassword 'KK'
            keyAlias = 'V'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    //implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'

    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.13'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.35.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:19.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'

    //implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0"
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.13.1'

    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.fenchtose.nocropper:nocropper:0.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation "me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.22@aar"
    implementation 'com.github.stfalcon:frescoimageviewer:0.5.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.1.0'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.1'
    implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:2.22.0'
    //implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:3.12.0'
}
```

Comment: jdk version?? Remove `bin` folder and run project

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya how do I check my jdk version?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30631286/how-to-specify-the-jdk-version-in-android-studio

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I followed the step I didn't see the version I also run command `java -version `, I got "To use the 'java' command-line tool you need to install a JDK"

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I just installed JDK 14.0.1

Comment: 52 is Java 8; 53 is Java 9.