# Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.8"

Tags: flutter, android-studio

Im new to flutter. Im running on macos catalina(10.15.7 (19H15)). I installed Flutter(2.2.3)

I download java 16 and installed it. And also i set the path.

```
java version "16.0.2" 2021-07-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 16.0.2+7-67)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.0.2+7-67, mixed mode, sharing)
```

```
thilinaabhisheka@Thilinas-MacBook-Air ~ % /usr/libexec/java_home -V      
Matching Java Virtual Machines (1):
    16.0.2, x86_64: "Java SE 16.0.2"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-16.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-16.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Im using Android studio 2020.3.1. when im run flutter doctor I got this error

```
Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.8".
Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.8".
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H15 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 2.2.3 at /Users/thilinaabhisheka/Developer/Flutter
    • Framework revision f4abaa0735 (8 weeks ago), 2021-07-01 12:46:11 -0700
    • Engine revision 241c87ad80
    • Dart version 2.13.4

⣟Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.8".                                                                                                                           [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/thilinaabhisheka/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: /usr/bin/java
    • Java version Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 16.0.2+7-67)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✗] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    ✗ Xcode installation is incomplete; a full installation is necessary for iOS development.
      Download at: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/
      Or install Xcode via the App Store.
      Once installed, run:
        sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
        sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
    ✗ CocoaPods not installed.
        CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
        Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
        For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
      To install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[!] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    ✗ Unable to find bundled Java version.
    • Try updating or re-installing Android Studio.

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)
    • Chrome (web)                       • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 92.0.4515.159

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Comment: Install java 8 or 1.8 - it might be possible to install it through the IDE

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history

Comment: java 1.8 works. thanks mate

Answer (score 3):

Install homebrew

now try it brew install --cask homebrew/cask-versions/adoptopenjdk8

Comment: Thanks!, it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

if you have used an android studio then set from the project structure. [image]

Comment: I set it. it wasn't fix the problem.

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30631286/how-to-specify-the-jdk-version-in-android-studio