# Why is JAVA version not detected? Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I am trying to build app in App Center. Build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.30"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "com.bugsnag:bugsnag-android-gradle-plugin:7.0.0"
    }
}
```

App build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "kotlin-android"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    ndkVersion "17.2.4988734"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.bugsnag.android"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias "password"
            keyPassword "password"
            storeFile file("../fakekeys.jks")
            storePassword "password"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild.cmake.path "CMakeLists.txt"
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "com.bugsnag:bugsnag-android:5.12.0"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0"
}

apply plugin: "com.bugsnag.android.gradle"
bugsnag.failOnUploadError = false
```

Why is JAVA 11 not detected? How to test this?

I am not sure if my ANdroid Studio has JAVA 11,image below shows Moules for my Project
[image]

It shows
[image]

Gradle properties
[image]

App Center build log

```
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
   > Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
     You can try some of the following options:
       - changing the IDE settings.
       - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
       - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.
```

How to edit gradle.properties? org.gradle.java.home = WHAT?

If JDK 11 is resolved,why build fails?

Comment: The answer is probably in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30631286/ or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487406.  Read them, and if I am right, delete this question.

Comment: @StephenC I edited my problem.

Comment: @MikiBelavista Post your full error log.

Comment: @JustInCoding Added right now.

Comment: @JustInCoding How to edit gradle.properties? org.gradle.java.home = WHAT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two solutions for your problem:

1. In the gradle.properties file at the project level, you can add a property called `org.gradle.java.home=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk11.0.0` (Don't add quotation marks before or after the path)
2. Put JDK 11 path in your `PATH` environment variable, and remove all other JDKs from it.

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to put with \\ instead of \ and without the \bin (until the previous directory).

Comment: if you want see video for solution see hare https://youtu.be/9mmY8rLvoRU

Comment: @Codeplayon please don't self-promote your videos in the comments section of others' answers