# Error on startActivity, but only on android 7 devices

Tags: android, android-activity, android-7.0-nougat, android-bundle, android-7.1-nougat

Since I updated my phone (Samsung Galaxy S7) to the new Android 7.0 two days ago I'm getting sporadically an error when running my app. It occurs sometimes (average every fifth time) when starting the `Activity_C` with `startActivity`:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.my.app/de.my.app.gui.Activity_C}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Bad magic number for Bundle: 0x620061`
(full stack trace below)

`Activity_C` inherits from `Activity_B` which itself inherits from `Activity_A`. `Activity_A` extends `AppCompatActivity` form the package `android.support.v7.app`.

Activity A, B and C have a `onCreate` method which start like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

When the error occurs the `savedInstanceState` is defenitly `null`. The `startActivity` call is always the same (`context.startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), Activity_C.class));`) and from the same activity.

I have searched for hours but found nothing useful. I'm not a newbie but also no expert; but it looks to me so that the problem is not in my activities, but something of the android system stuff.

I'm now using the latest sdk (25) with the appropriate support-packages (25.1.0) but the error also occurs on the sdk v23 I used before. On other devices running Android 5 or 6 everything still works fine.

Does someone know why this problem occurs and how to deal with it?

This is the full stack trace:

```
01-27 21:36:45.241 9953-9953/de.my.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                        Process: de.my.app, PID: 9953
                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.my.app/de.my.app.gui.Activity_C}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Bad magic number for Bundle: 0x620061
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2947)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3008)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688)
                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
                                                         Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Bad magic number for Bundle: 0x620061
                                                            at android.os.BaseBundle.readFromParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1443)
                                                            at android.os.BaseBundle.<init>(BaseBundle.java:128)
                                                            at android.os.Bundle.<init>(Bundle.java:69)
                                                            at android.os.Parcel.readBundle(Parcel.java:1888)
                                                            at android.os.Parcel.readBundle(Parcel.java:1872)
                                                            at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.<init>(PackageItemInfo.java:466)
                                                            at android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo.<init>(ApplicationInfo.java:1311)
                                                            at android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo.<init>(ApplicationInfo.java)
                                                            at android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo$1.createFromParcel(ApplicationInfo.java:1303)
                                                            at android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo$1.createFromParcel(ApplicationInfo.java:1302)
                                                            at android.content.pm.ComponentInfo.<init>(ComponentInfo.java:228)
                                                            at android.content.pm.ActivityInfo.<init>(ActivityInfo.java:1025)
                                                            at android.content.pm.ActivityInfo.<init>(ActivityInfo.java)
                                                            at android.content.pm.ActivityInfo$1.createFromParcel(ActivityInfo.java:1017)
                                                            at android.content.pm.ActivityInfo$1.createFromParcel(ActivityInfo.java:1016)
                                                            at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.getActivityInfo(IPackageManager.java:3157)
                                                            at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getActivityInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:484)
                                                            at android.support.v4.app.NavUtils.getParentActivityName(NavUtils.java:301)
                                                            at android.support.v4.app.NavUtils.getParentActivityName(NavUtils.java:281)
                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:157)
                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:60)
                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:76)
                                                            at de.my.app.gui.Activity_A.onCreate(Activity_A.java:39)
                                                            at de.my.app.gui.Activity_B.onCreate(Activity_B.java:43)
                                                            at de.my.app.gui.Activity_C.onCreate(Activity_C.java:50)
                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6912)
                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2900)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3008) 
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650) 
                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688) 
                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468) 
                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

Comment: are you using parecel?

Comment: show us some more code

Comment: only in other classes; it's difficult, because I don't know which parts my be important for this problem..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26202149/bad-magic-number-for-bundle-in-android

Comment: this error sometimes encounters because of low version of google play services try upgrading play service and check if it still persists

Comment: I checked it another time, parcels are not used around there. Also no line of the `onCreate` methods should be executed before the error occurs

Comment: except the `super.onCreate(..)` of curse

Comment: I now updated google play services to the latest version (10.2.91) but the problem still occurs.

Comment: After updating the `com.google.android.gms:play-services` as well as the firebase-dependencies in the `gradle.build` file of the app module to 10.0.1 it seems to work fine... but I'm not absolutely sure... Anyway thanks for your help!