# IllegalStateException: Bad magic number for Bundle

Tags: android, parcelable, illegalstateexception

Getting following error in Android while getting the control back to app after phone call ends. We have checked the complete code and confirmed that all objects implemented **Serializable** and while passing the data from one activity to another activity.

We are storing the values/objects first in Bundle and then push it to intent. However, when in-app call ends, and getting control back to app, at that time, application is getting crashed.

Error is given below.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Bad magic number for Bundle: 0x6f0063
at android.os.BaseBundle.readFromParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1346)
at android.os.BaseBundle.readFromParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1334)
at android.os.Bundle.readFromParcel(Bundle.java:1046)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$zza$zza.onSaveInstanceState(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$zza.onSaveInstanceState(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onSaveInstanceState(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onSaveInstanceState(Unknown Source)
at android.app.Fragment.performSaveInstanceState(Fragment.java:2198)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentBasicState(FragmentManager.java:1605)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveAllState(FragmentManager.java:1662)
at android.app.Fragment.performSaveInstanceState(Fragment.java:2200)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentBasicState(FragmentManager.java:1605)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveAllState(FragmentManager.java:1662)
at android.app.Activity.onSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1389)
at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1320)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.callCallActivityOnSaveInstanceState(ActivityThread.java:3973)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3384)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3440)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5273)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

Comment: Post some lines of your Serializable class

Comment: public class Bus implements Serializable {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 private String BusID, BusOperatorID;

 public String getBusID() {
  return BusID;
 }

 public void setBusID(String busID) {
  BusID = busID;
 }

 public String getBusOperatorID() {
  return BusOperatorID;
 }

 public void setBusOperatorID(String busOperatorID) {
  BusOperatorID = busOperatorID;
 } 
}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bad magic number for Bundle in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26202149/bad-magic-number-for-bundle-in-android)